# Move information-resource stored in the database tables with two step using 'reservation'

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to architect a database and service, I have resource that I need to deliver to the users. And the delivery takes some time or requires user to do some more job.

These are the tables I store information into.

```
Table   - Description
_______________________
R       - to store resources
RESERVE - to reserve requested resources
HACK    - to track some requests that couldn`t be made with my client application (statistics)
FAIL    - to track requests that can`t be resolved, but the user isn't guilty (statistics)
SUCCESS - to track successfully delivery (statistics)
```

The first step when a user requests resouce

```
IF (condition1 is true - user have the right to request resource) THEN
    IF (i've successfully RESERVE-d resource and commited the transaction) THEN
        nothing to do more
    ELSE
        save request into FAIL
ELSE
    save request into HACK
```

Then the second step

```
IF (condition2 is true - user done his job and requests the reserved resource) THEN
    IF (the resource delivered successfully) THEN
        save request into SUCCESS
    ELSE
        save request into FAIL
        depending on application logic move resource from RESERVE to R or not
ELSE
    save request into HACK, contact to the user, 
    if this is really a hacker move resource from RESERVE to R
```

This is how I think to implement the system. I've stored transactions into the procedures. But the main application logic, where I decide which procedure to call are done in the application/service layer.

Am I on a right way, is such code division between the db and the service layers normal? Your experienced opinions are very important.

Clarifying and answering to RecentCoin's questions.

1. The difference between the `HACK` and `FAIL` tables are that I store more information in the `HACK` table, like `user IP` and `XFF`. I`m not going to penalize each user that appeared in that table. There can be 2 reasons that a user(request) is tracked as a hack. The first is that I have a bug (mainly in the client app) and this will help me to fix them. The second is that someone does manually requests, and tries to bypass the rules. If he tries 'harder' I'll be able to take some precautions.
2. The separation of the `reserve` and the `success` tables has these reasons. 
   2.1. I use `reserve` table in some transactions and queries without using the `success` table, so I can lock them separately.
   2.2. The data stored in `success` will not slow down my queries, wile I'm querying the `reserve` table.
   2.3. The `success` table is kind of a log for statistics, that I can delete or move to other database for future analyse.
   2.4. I delete the rows from the `reserve` after I move them to the `success` table. So I can evaluate approximately the max rows count in that table, because I have max limit for reservations for each user.

The points 2.3 and 2.4 could be achieved too by keeping in one table.
So are the reasons 2.1 and 2.2 enough good to keep the data separately?

3. The resource "delivered successfully" mean that the admin and the service are done everything they could do successfully, if they couldn't then the reservation fails

4 and 6. The restrictions and right are simple, they are like city and country restrictions, The users are 'flat', don't have any roles or hierarchy.

5. I have some tables to store users and their information. I don't have LDAP or AD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going in the right direction, but there are some other things that need to be more clearly thought out.

1. You're going to have to define what constitutes a "hack" vs a "fail". Especially with new systems, users get confused and it's pretty easy for them to make honest mistakes. This seems like something you want to penalize them for in some fashion so I'd be extremely careful with this.
2. You will want to consider having "reserve" and "success" be equivalent. Why store the same record twice? You should have a really compelling reason do that.
3. You will need to define "delivered successfully" since that could be anything from an entry in a calendar to getting more pens and post notes.
4. You will want to define your resources as well as which user(s) have rights to them.  For example, you may have a conference room that only managers are allowed to book, but you might want to include the managers' administrative assistants in that list since they would be booking the room for the manager(s).
5. Do you have a database of users?  LDAP or Active Directory or will you need to create all of that yourself?  If you do have LDAP or AD, can use something like SAML?

6.You are going to want to consider how you want to assign those rights.  Will they be group based where group membership confers the rights to reserve, request, or use a given thing?  For example, you may only want architects printing to the large format printer.

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate your help and time to analyse this abstract question. I've re-analysed everything once more and updated the question prior your answer.